# How to create a pagination in Express.Js?

Tags: node.js, api, express, pagination

I'm creating an API that takes data from a 3rd party API as well, which does not have pagination. I would like to create a pagination of 10 elements per page for some endpoints, I tried some guides but I fail in creating the pagination.

My code is the following:

```
const Policies = require("../services/policiesApi");

exports.policies_list = (async (req, res, next) => {
    const policiesList = await Policies.getPolicies;
    console.log(policiesCount);
    res.send(await policiesList)
});
```

As you can see, I extract the data from the 3rd party API in another file and I export it to the controller, where I export as well to the routes.

The route file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();

// Controller modules
const policies_controller = require("../controllers/policiesController");

 router.get('/policies', policies_controller.policies_list);

//Exporting routers
module.exports = router;
```

Inside the route and the controllers there are other endpoints, but they don't need to have pagination (as they are taking the info of an id, for example).
I tried to use express-paginate and paginate-info but I can't make it work.
I would really appreciate if you can help me with this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a separate pagination function, which takes input data and returns it in a paginated form. This function takes necessary parameters if you want to select certain fields, populate and sort them.

```
results = {};
results.totalNumber = await model[0].countDocuments(find);
const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
const endIndex = page * limit;

if (startIndex > 0) {
   results.previous = {
   limit: limit,
   page: page - 1,
   };
}

if (endIndex < results.totalNumber) {
   results.next = {
   limit: limit,
   page: page + 1,
   };
}
    
try {
   results.results = await model[0].find(find_obj).select(select_string)
     .skip(startIndex).limit(limit).sort(sort_obj)
     .populate(populate_obj).lean();
   return results;
} catch (err) {
   return new ErrorResponse('Error!', 500);
}
```